# how to force killing process in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, service, command-line

i'm trying to kill a process running in the background of an  Ubuntu platform, using `sudo kill<process_number>` before that i used `sudo lsof -t -i:<port_number>` to know exactly the process number. 
my question is: in what case this method doesn't work, "in my case the process still running" , how i force stop such a process ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: try `kill -9 <process_number>` (9 is SIGKILL). See the documentation for `kill` for more info and [How to kill a process in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu#104908).

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a neat way to find a process and kill it.

There are many ways to achieve this `kill -9` being the simplest.

That said, for your puropse I recommend taking a look at `htop`. (`sudo apt-get install htop`).

From what you described, it should be equivalent to your current described method, but slightly quicker, clearer and offering learning opportunities along the way.

***`htop` usage matching your explained need:***

From a terminal you can type `htop` to open a list of processes, it will show CPU and memory usage along with some other useful statistics. From there use the arrow keys to select the process you wish to kill. Once the process is highlighted, you can press `f9` to bring up the kill menu, here you'll see all the signals you can send to the process. Select 9 for kill (by using the arrow keys, or pressing the number key (`9`), then hit enter. Press `q` to quit htop.

This is equivalent to `kill -9` but you can see other signal interrupt options for the sake of exploration and learning. To search for a process in `htop` (let's say you're looking for a python process, you can hit `/` and then type "python" followed by `enter`.

Hope that helps. Ultimately the method you use is up to you, `htop` offers a lot of clearly laid-out information and tools to manage processes. You can also use `top`, `kill`, `pkill` and others with a little research. If you don't know yet, `man` (short for manual) can be used preceding any of these commands, to learn more about them. For example `man kill` will explain the use of the kill command and give examples of use.